# How can I find the element that would have been targeted by a given fragment identifier?

Tags: javascript, dom, queryselector, fragment-identifier

When a browser navigates to an URL like `http://example.com/#foo`, it scrolls to the element identified by `#foo`; this element of the URI is called a fragment identifier.  Suppose I have a fragment identifier for an element on the current page, which I have *not* yet navigated to.  How can I find out which DOM node would have been targeted by it?

- It’s not enough to use `document.getElementById`, because a fragment identifier `#foo` can also target an old-style anchor, `<a name="foo">`, which this method misses.
- It’s not correct to use `document.getElementsByName` either, because that would find non-anchors like `<input>` or `<textarea>` nodes, *and* miss elements identified by the `id=` attribute.
- Since I have not navigated at the fragment, I cannot use `document.querySelector(':target')` either.

Is there a reliable way to find which DOM node would have been targeted by fragment identifier that catches all cases?  If the solution uses `querySelector`, I would of course like it to be robust against unusual characters found within identifiers, however deprecated they may be.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/anchors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector is the easiest way to say "An element with an ID or an `a` element with a name".

`CSS.escape` will handle special characters for you.

```
const fragment_id = `fdfd""fewf"`; // The test string I used for this
const escaped_fragment_id = CSS.escape(fragment_id);
const element = document.querySelector(`#${escaped_fragment_id}, a[name="${escaped_fragment_id}"`)
```

Note that you might also need to use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) if the source of `fragment_id` has been escaped.

Comment: This solution is not quite correct. [The specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#find-a-potential-indicated-element) ask to return the first element with an id matching the fragment, or the first `<a>` with a name matching this fragment. This solution will return whatever of these is the first to come. So in a (I admit, improbable) case like `<a name=fragment></a><i id=fragment></i>` the `<i>` should have been returned but here it will return `<a>`. Easily fixed by calling twice `querySelector()`  https://jsfiddle.net/grw5cfzq/